# Custom validation error message doesn't display in Html.ValidationSummary

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I've created a custom validation attribute to apply to my view model. In my form, I have a `@Html.ValidationSummary` control. When my custom validation attribute is invalid, the summary control doesn't display the error message for some reason.

Here's my custom validator:

```
public class UserFolderExistsAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    private const string _defaultErrorMessage = 
        "A folder with this name already exists";
    private readonly object _typeId = new object();

    public UserFolderExistsAttribute(string folderName) :
        base(_defaultErrorMessage)
    {
        FolderName = folderName;
    }

    public string FolderName { get; private set; }
    public override object TypeId { get { return _typeId; } }

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        return false; // return error message to test for now
    }
}
```

Here's my view model, with my custom validator attribute applied:

```
[UserFolderExists("Name")]
public class UserFolderViewModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Name is required")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Here's my partial view:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Create", "Folders",
    new AjaxOptions { OnSuccess = "OnSuccess" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name, new { placeholder = "Name" })

    <p>@Html.ValidationSummary()</p>

    <p><input type="submit" class="create" value="" /></p>
}
```

Here's the method my form is posting to:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Create(UserFolderViewModel viewModel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // do something
    }

    return Json("error");  
}
```

The `ModelState.IsValid` attribute returns false, so it recognizes my custom validator. But the summary control doesn't automatically display my message. The summary does recognize the `Required` data annotation validator, and displays the error message.

How can I get the Validation Summary to display my custom error message?

Answer (score 0):

You are returning a `JsonResult` object with just a string `"error"` inside, how is MVC able to know what validation message to show on the client-side? If you use normal posting (with `ActionResult`) you can just return the same model and the validation messages will appear:

```
return View(viewModel);
```

You can also validate the object yourself in the controller and return an error message through the `JsonResult` class by using `return Json("error message here");`

*Or* you could try to get the validation error messages from the `ModelState` property and return them with Json. Check out the second answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5212248/get-error-message-if-modelstate-isvalid-fails).