# How to check if a datetime value is empty or not in a put request

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, httprequest, put

in my controller i'm trying to check if a datetime value is being passed through in a put request but when i don't send a value for that datetime field it will reset the value in the database to 01/01/0001/ here is the code in my controller how i check if its empty or not.( a little bit of it ) (Check user.Age!)

```
[HttpPut("User/Edit/{userid}")]
    public IActionResult Update(string token, int userid, [FromBody]User user)
    {


        bool RoleId = JWTValidator.RoleIDTokenValidation(token);
        var edit = _context.users.Find(userid);
        if (RoleId)
        {
            if (user.Name != null)
            {
                edit.Name = user.Name;
            }
            else
            {
                edit.Name = edit.Name;
            }
            if (user.LastName != null)
            {
                edit.LastName = user.LastName;
            }
            else
            {
                edit.LastName = edit.LastName;
            }
            if (user.Age != null)
            {
                edit.Age = user.Age;
            }
            else
            {
                edit.Age = edit.Age;
            }
```

so if the value is null it won't update but i guess if you don't enter anything it will see it as 01/01/0001 so i tried comparing to it like this

```
if(user.Age == "01/01/0001")
```

but i can't compare type datetime to a string. and also i'm using validation like this

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    _context.users.Update(edit);
                    _context.SaveChanges();
                }
                else
                {
                    return BadRequest(ModelState);
                }
```

and my model for Age is

```
[Display(Name = "Your Birthday")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date, ErrorMessage = "Not a correct date format, MM/DD/YYYY please.")]
    public DateTime Age { get; set; }
```

but if i send a put request with contents "Age": "test" it just gives me a 500 internal error instead of giving me the errormessage, am i handling that wrong?

Hope anyone could help me out.

Comment: Use `DateTime.MinValue` instead of that string.

Comment: Probably it helps to make the DateTime nullable as well.

Comment: You don't need those `else` statements where they set a property to it's own existing value...

Comment: You're really using `Age` to name a date/time value? Don't you think that's going to confuse people? When somebody asks your age, you don't say, "12/26/1999". You say, "I'm 19 years old." Please name the variable something like `BirthDate`. That'll be a log less confusing.

Comment: Yeah sorry, I was gonna do that but was first wanted to fix this problem @JimMischel

Comment: @RufusL yeah i realized, i'm taking them all out of all my Requests. Would this improve performance in anyway? theoretically i mean because this won't impact my performance a lot i assume but imagine if I had a huge site.

Comment: I doubt if it affected performance it would be enough to notice and possibly the compiler will optimize it away. But it's a lot of extra code to read.

Answer (score 1):

Well if you are looking for something to replace this if(user.Age == "01/01/0001")

Here you have a simple example: Returns 0 if is the same date

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("01/01/0001 00:00:00", "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); //Use your default date string and your format type
DateTime dt2 = DateTime.Now;//Use Your Specific Date
var dtComp = DateTime.Compare(dt, dt2);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also declare age as nullable, i.e:

```
DateTime? user.Age  = new DateTime();
```

You can then easily check for null an also simply set edit.Age like this(if you want a default value):

```
edit.Age = user.Age ?? new DateTime(1970,01,01);
```

regards.

Answer (score 1):

```
DateTime  myDate;
if(myDate.Date == DateTime.MinValue)
{
    //Do!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the problem here is that you need to compare a `struct` to its default value, which is not `null`. To do this, you can simply use the `default` keyword to get the default value for the type. Note that you can do this with classes as well as structs:

```
if (user.Age != default(DateTime))
{
    edit.Age = user.Age;
}
```

Comment: Oh, I did like Nyer said and used DateTime.MinValue and it worked perfectly. but I'll try this a swell

Comment: Cool, that make sense. `MinValue` happens to be the default for `DateTime`, but this option makes it so you don't have to know that, and you can use it with any type, for example: `if (user.LastName != default(string))`

Comment: But then i have another question that i asked in this post, Why does it return a 500 server error when i input a wrong format for type datetime, for example "Birthday": "test" changed Age to Birthday btw. check the original post for validation statement and model for Birthday

Comment: Look through the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5212248/get-error-message-if-modelstate-isvalid-fails) for some ideas on how to display the error message.