# Why parameter of the action method is null when view is posted?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

This is an ASP.NET MVC project. I have a view that displays a collection of `BookRentViewModel` items.

When I click on the button in the view, the view is posted to an action method called `rent`. `rent` action method has a parameter called items of type `IEnumerable<BookRentViewModel>`.

Here is the code of the view:

```
@model IEnumerable<DaramSerl.Models.ViewModels.BookRentViewModel>
@using (Html.BeginForm("rent", "RentBook", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
{
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.bookName)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.isRented)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.startDate)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.endDate)
            </th>
        </tr>

        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.bookName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.isRented)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.startDate)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.endDate)
                </td>
            </tr>
        }

    </table>

    <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
}
```

And here is the action method:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> rent(IEnumerable<BookRentViewModel> items)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("/Index");
    }
    return View();
}
```

And here is the BookRentViewModel:

```
public class BookRentViewModel
{
    [Key]
    public int bookId{ get; set; }
    public string bookName { get; set; }
    public bool isRented { get; set; }
    public DateTime startDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime endDate { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is that `items` parameter is always null when `rent` action is triggered.

Any idea why `items` is null and does not get the collection from the view?

**UPDATE**
I used fiddler to see if the collection is posted to the server but it seems it cannot be parsed  into  BookRentViewModel items.

**UPDATE3**
Here is screenshot from fiddler with the collection sent from the view:
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10984040/post-parameter-is-always-null

Comment: Why do you want all of the data being submitted? What does the form **do**?

Comment: The updated data from fiddler looks ok, but it would be much easier to see the problem if you posted the raw request body - which you can get from your browsers network tab in dev tools.

Comment: I'm betting this is your problem. https://stackoverflow.com/a/17037925/7840778

Comment: @SteveLand thanks it worked!!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass IEnumerable list to controller in MVC including checkbox state?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17037858/how-to-pass-ienumerable-list-to-controller-in-mvc-including-checkbox-state)

Answer (score 1):

Doesnt look like you're setting a value for `public int bookId` - if thats the case this will fail validation as its a non-nullable type.

Either way, set a breakpoint in your controller method and check the errors on `ModelState` - see [Get error message if ModelState.IsValid fails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5212248/get-error-message-if-modelstate-isvalid-fails)

**Edit**

To include properties but not show them on your view, use the hidden field razor tag helper:
`@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.bookId)`

Comment: Ok, please add the request body to your question then.

Answer (score 0):

I tried reproduce source code.

You can change model mapping in cshtml file as below

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count();i++ )
        { 
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.TextBox("items[" + @i + "].bookName", 
                        Model.ElementAt(i).bookName 
                        )</td>
                <td>@Html.CheckBox("items[" + @i + "].isRented",
                        Model.ElementAt(i).isRented
                        )</td>
                <td>@Html.TextBox("items[" + @i + "].startDate",
                        Model.ElementAt(i).startDate
                        )</td>
                <td>@Html.TextBox("items[" + @i + "].endDate",
                        Model.ElementAt(i).endDate
                        )</td>

            </tr>
        }
```

rent.cshtml file

```
@model IEnumerable<WebApplication2.Controllers.BookRentViewModel>
@using (Html.BeginForm("rent", "Rent", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
{
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.bookName)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.isRented)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.startDate)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.endDate)
            </th>
        </tr>

        @*@foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.bookName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.isRented)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.startDate)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.endDate)
                </td>
            </tr>
        }*@

        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count();i++ )
        { 
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.TextBox("items[" + @i + "].bookName", 
                        Model.ElementAt(i).bookName 
                        )</td>
                <td>@Html.CheckBox("items[" + @i + "].isRented",
                        Model.ElementAt(i).isRented
                        )</td>
                <td>@Html.TextBox("items[" + @i + "].startDate",
                        Model.ElementAt(i).startDate
                        )</td>
                <td>@Html.TextBox("items[" + @i + "].endDate",
                        Model.ElementAt(i).endDate
                        )</td>

            </tr>
        }

    </table>

    <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
}
```