# Model is Invalid always - Getting error every time add a Data With EF Core

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor, pagedlist

I am using ASP.Net Corre 3.1. My Model is like this-

```
public class Review: BaseEntity
{
    [Required]
    [Range(1,10)]
    public float Rating { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Movie Watch date should be given")]
    [Display(Name = "Date of Watch", Prompt = "Please Give Date of Watch the Movie")]
    public DateTime WatchDate { get; set; }

    //public virtual string UserId { get; set; }     //Not Needed because they are automatically handled by Dot.Net Core
    [Required]
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public virtual User User { get; set; }

    //public virtual string MovieId { get; set; }    //Not Needed because they are automatically handled by Dot.Net Core
    [Required]
    public virtual Movie Movie { get; set; }
}
```

**BaseEntity** is like this-

```
public class BaseEntity
{
    //[MaxLength(255)]
    [Key, Required, Column(TypeName = "VARCHAR(255)")]
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    //[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)] //Not Needed
    public DateTime? UpdatedDate { get; set; }
}
```

My ***View*** is like this-

```
<form asp-action="Create">
    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Rating" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="Rating" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Rating" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="WatchDate" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="WatchDate" readonly type="text" placeholder="Click to set start-date" class="DatePicker form-control" id="start_date">
        <span asp-validation-for="WatchDate" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Movie" class="control-label"></label>
        <select asp-for="Movie" asp-items="ViewBag.Movies" class="form-control">
            <option disabled selected>-- Please Select a Movie to Review --</option>
        </select>
        <span asp-validation-for="Movie" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
    </div>
</form>
```

And my ***Controller*** is like this-

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Rating,WatchDate,Movie")] Review review)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        review.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
        _context.Add(review);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }
    //ViewBag.Movies and ViewData["Movies"] => Both are same
    ViewData["Movies"] = new SelectList(await _context.Movies.ToListAsync(), "Id", "Name", review.Movie);
    return View(review);
}
```

I am getting my view showing error message - 'Model is Invalid'.

can anyone please help?

Comment: You [Bind] only _Rating,WatchDate,Movie_ but the model has the attribute [Required] on User and the base has other required fields

Comment: All the base fields can be ignored

Answer (score 0):

You can check what properties has not passed validation by getting [errors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13968078/2501279), but i would say it was `User` property which is marked as `Required` in your `Review` class ind `Id` from `BaseEntity` while your form and bind have only Rating, WatchDate and Movie. I would suggest adding separate class for modeling review creation data and setting up separate validation for it.