# Submit button is not firing in ASP.NET MVC web application

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I am new to ASP.NET and C#, by looking some tutorial I tried to make a site for voting but the submit button is not working at all, have tried all the solutions given here but still, now it is not working.

Home Controller:

```cs
namespace test.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult voted(Vote_Results Vote, string Hafiza, string Mridul, string Ranvir, string Sayan, string Sourav, string Shusovan)
        {
            string message = "";
            //Model Validation
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                #region Email Existance
                var isExist = IsEmailExist(Vote.Email_Id);
                if (isExist)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("EmailExist", "Candidate has Already Voted!");
                    return View(Vote);
                }

                #endregion

                #region binding extra property
                if (Hafiza == "true")
                {
                    Vote.Hafiza_Khatun = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    Vote.Hafiza_Khatun = false;
                }

                if (Mridul == "true")
                {
                    Vote.Mridul_Bose = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    Vote.Mridul_Bose = false;
                }

                if (Ranvir == "true")
                {
                    Vote.Ranvir_Baral = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    Vote.Ranvir_Baral = false;
                }

                if (Sourav == "true")
                {
                    Vote.Sourav_Kr_Halder = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    Vote.Sourav_Kr_Halder = false;
                }

                if (Shusovan == "true")
                {
                    Vote.Shusovan_Chakraborty = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    Vote.Shusovan_Chakraborty = false;
                }

                if (Sayan == "true")
                {
                    Vote.Sayan_Parui = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    Vote.Sayan_Parui = false;
                }

                Vote.is_voted = true;
                Vote.TimeStamp = DateTime.Now;
                #endregion

                #region save data to database
                using (PR_Vote_21Entities db = new PR_Vote_21Entities())
                {
                    db.Vote_Results.Add(Vote);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    //send Email to user
                    SendConfirmationEmail(Vote.Email_Id, Vote.Name);
                    message = Vote.Name + ",<br>Your Responce Has been submited SUCCESSFULLY!<br>" + "You will recieve an Email Shortly!";
                    Response.Write(message);
                //Logout();
                }
                #endregion
            }
            else
            {
                message = "Invalid Request";
                Response.Write(message);
            }

            return View();
        }

        [NonAction]
        public bool IsEmailExist(string emailID)
        {
            using (PR_Vote_21Entities dc = new PR_Vote_21Entities())
            {
                var v = dc.Vote_Results.Where(a => a.Email_Id == emailID).FirstOrDefault();
                return v != null;
            }
        }

        [NonAction]
        public void SendConfirmationEmail(string emailID, string Name)
        {
            var fromEmail = new MailAddress("email@domain.com", "name");
            var toEmail = new MailAddress(emailID);
            var fromEmailPassword = "PW";
            string subject = "Your vote is successfully submited!";
            string body = "<div> Hi," + Name + "<br><br> Your response has been submitted successfully.<br>" + "Thank you <br><br> Do Not Replay, It is an autogenerated Mail <br> DEE | PRSV </div>";
            var smtp = new SmtpClient{Host = "smtp.gmail.com", Port = 587, EnableSsl = true, DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network, UseDefaultCredentials = false, Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromEmail.Address, fromEmailPassword)};
            using (var message = new MailMessage(fromEmail, toEmail)
            {Subject = subject, Body = body, IsBodyHtml = true})
                smtp.Send(message);
        }
    }
}
```

HTML page:

```
@model test.Models.Vote_Results
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="Mark Otto, Jacob Thornton, and Bootstrap contributors">
    <meta name="generator" content="Hugo 0.87.0">
    <title> PRV-DEE</title>

    <link rel="canonical" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/examples/jumbotron/">



    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <!-- Favicons -->
    <link rel="icon" href="~/Assets/TitleImg.png" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#7952b3">


    <style>
        .bd-placeholder-img {
            font-size: 1.125rem;
            text-anchor: middle;
            -webkit-user-select: none;
            -moz-user-select: none;
            user-select: none;
        }

        @@media (min-width: 768px) {
            .bd-placeholder-img-lg {
                font-size: 3.5rem;
            }
        }

        .Candidate {
            font-size: 20px;
        }

        .big-checkbox {
            width: 20px;
            height: 20px;
        }

        .hide {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>

    <!--Special Scripts-->
    <script src="../Assets/votesite.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")

    <main>
        <div class="container py-4">
            <header class="pb-3 mb-4 border-bottom">
                <a href="/" class="d-flex align-items-center text-dark text-decoration-none">
                    <img src="~/Assets/TitleImg.png" width="40" height="40">
                    <span class="fs-4"> &nbsp;&nbsp;PR SELECTION</span>
                </a>
            </header>

            <div class="p-5 mb-4 bg-light rounded-3">
                <div class="container-fluid py-5">
                    <h1 class="display-5 fw-bold" style="color:#03b603;">RULES </h1>
                    <ol class="col-md-12 fs-5">
                        <li>No 2nd vote will be taken, If a 2nd vote is found in someone's name his/her vote will be canceled.</li>
                        <li>If someone is found to be cheating he will be disqualified from voting.</li>
                        <li>Don't Share your <b>Password</b> and <b>DOB</b> with anyone until&nbsp;the voting process is completed.</li>
                        <li>Strictly 3 Candidates must be chosen from the list.</li>
                        <li>Don't share your voting config with others.</li>
                    </ol>
                    <div class="form-check" style="margin-top: 30px;">
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="agree" onclick="visible()">
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="flexCheckDefault">
                            I Agree with Above Rules
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            @using (Html.BeginForm("voted", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
            {
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                <div class="row align-items-md-stretch hide" id="P-Details">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="h-100 p-5 bg-dark rounded-3">
                            <h2 class="text-white">Insert Your Details</h2>
                            <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Reg_No, new { htmlAttributes = new { @type = "text", @class = "form-control", @id = "Reg", @placeholder = "D123456789", @onchange = "count()" } })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Reg_No, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                @*<input type="text" class="form-control" id="Reg" placeholder="D123456789" onchange="count()">*@
                                <label for="Reg">Registration No</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-floating">
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DOB, new { htmlAttributes = new { @type = "date", @class = "form-control", @id = "DOB", @placeholder = "07-Sep-2021", @onchange = "count()" } })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DOB, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                @*<input type="date" class="form-control" id="DOB" placeholder="07-Sep-2021" onchange="count()">*@
                                <label for="floatingInputValue" color="red">Date Of Birth</label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="h-100 p-5 bg-light border rounded-3">
                            <h2>Non-Changable Details</h2>
                            <form>
                                <div class="form-floating">
                                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email_Id, new { htmlAttributes = new { @type = "text", @class = "form-control", @id = "Email", @placeholder = "name@example.com", @Value = "name", @disabled = "disabled" } })
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email_Id, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                    @*<input type="text" class="form-control" id="floatingInputValue" placeholder="name@example.com" value="koustavshee.work@gmail.com" disabled>*@
                                    <label for="floatingInputValue">E-mail address</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-floating" style=" margin-top:5px">
                                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @type = "text", @class = "form-control", @id = "fullName", @placeholder = "example Name", @Value = "name@domain.com", @disabled = "disabled" } })
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                    @*<input type="text" class="form-control" id="floatingInputValue" placeholder="example Name" value="Koustav Shee" disabled>*@
                                    <label for="floatingInputValue">Full Name</label>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="p-5 mb-4 bg-light rounded-3 hide" style="margin-top:20px" id="Candidates">
                    <div class="container-fluid py-5">
                        <h1 class="display-5 fw-bold" style="color:#03b603; margin-bottom:20px">PR Candidates</h1>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="form-check col" style="margin-top: 10px;">
                                @Html.CheckBox("Hafiza", false, new { @class = "form-check-input big-checkbox", @type = "checkbox", @id = "can1", @onclick = "count()" })
                                @*@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Hafiza_Khatun, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-check-input big-checkbox", @type = "checkbox", @id = "can3", @onclick = "count()", @Value = "" } })*@
                                <label class="form-check-label Candidate" for="flexCheckDefault">
                                    &nbsp;Hafiza_cc
                                </label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-check col" style="margin-top: 10px;">
                                @Html.CheckBox("Mridul", false, new { @class = "form-check-input big-checkbox", @type = "checkbox", @id = "can2", @onclick = "count()" })
                                @*<input class="form-check-input big-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="" id="can2" onclick="count()">*@
                                <label class="form-check-label Candidate" for="flexCheckDefault">
                                    &nbsp;Mridul_cc
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="form-check col" style="margin-top: 10px;">
                                @Html.CheckBox("Ranvir", false, new { @class = "form-check-input big-checkbox", @type = "checkbox", @id = "can3", @onclick = "count()" })
                                @*<input class="form-check-input big-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="" id="can3" onclick="count()">*@
                                <label class="form-check-label Candidate" for="flexCheckDefault">
                                    &nbsp;Ranvir_cc
                                </label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-check col" style="margin-top: 10px;">
                                @Html.CheckBox("Sayan", false, new { @class = "form-check-input big-checkbox", @type = "checkbox", @id = "can4", @onclick = "count()" })
                                @*<input class="form-check-input big-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="" id="can4" onclick="count()">*@
                                <label class="form-check-label Candidate" for="flexCheckDefault">
                                    &nbsp;Sayan_cc
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">

                            <div class="form-check col" style="margin-top: 10px;">
                                @Html.CheckBox("Sourav", false, new { @class = "form-check-input big-checkbox", @type = "checkbox", @id = "can5", @onclick = "count()" })
                                @*<input class="form-check-input big-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="" id="can5" onclick="count()">*@
                                <label class="form-check-label Candidate" for="flexCheckDefault">
                                    &nbsp;Sourav_cc
                                </label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-check col" style="margin-top: 10px;">
                                @Html.CheckBox("Shusovan", false, new { @class = "form-check-input big-checkbox", @type = "checkbox", @id = "can6", @onclick = "count()" })
                                @*<input class="form-check-input big-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="" id="can6" onclick="count()">*@
                                <label class="form-check-label Candidate" for="flexCheckDefault">
                                    &nbsp;Shusovan_cc
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <br />
                        <div class="d-grid gap-2 d-md-flex justify-content-md-end">

                            <button class="btn btn-primary me-md-2" type="submit" id="submit"
                                    disabled>
                                Submit Responce
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            }
            <footer class="pt-3 mt-4 text-muted border-top">
                institution | Department
            </footer>
        </div>
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

For Data validation, I have used this in another folder called extended and erased the folder name from the namespace

```cs
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace test.Models
{
    [MetadataType(typeof(Vote_ResultsMetaData))]
    public partial class Vote_Results
    {
    }

    public class Vote_ResultsMetaData
    {
        [Display(Name = "Email ID")]
        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Email Address Required")]
        [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
        public string Email_Id
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        [Display(Name = "Name")]
        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Name Required")]
        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        public string Name
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        [Display(Name = "Reg No")]
        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Registation No Required")]
        [MinLength(10, ErrorMessage = "Reg No is of 10 Characters")]
        [MaxLength(10, ErrorMessage = "Reg No is of 10 Characters")]
        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        public string Reg_No
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        [Display(Name = "DOB")]
        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "DOB Required")]
        [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:mm-dd-yyyy}")]
        public System.DateTime DOB
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
}
```

Actual class generated by Entity Framework:

```cs
namespace test.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    
    public partial class Vote_Results
    {
        public int pk_id { get; set; }
        public string Email_Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Reg_No { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime DOB { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> Hafiza_Khatun { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> Mridul_Bose { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> Ranvir_Baral { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> Saikat_Naskar { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> Sayan_Parui { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> Sourav_Kr_Halder { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> Shusovan_Chakraborty { get; set; }
        public bool is_voted { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Javascript file used for adding some action:

```js
function visible() {
    element = document.getElementById('agree')
    if (element.checked == true) {
        document.getElementById('P-Details').classList.remove('hide')
        document.getElementById('Candidates').classList.remove('hide')
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById('P-Details').classList.add('hide')
        document.getElementById('Candidates').classList.add('hide')
    }
}

function count() {
    var idArr = ['can1', 'can2', 'can3', 'can4', 'can5', 'can6']
    var inpArr = ['Reg', 'DOB']
    var N0 = 0
    var N1 = 0

    for (var i = 0; i < idArr.length; i++) {
        if (document.getElementById(idArr[i]).checked == true) {
            N0++;
        }
    }

    if (document.getElementById('Reg').value != "" && document.getElementById('DOB').value != "") {
        N1 = 2;
    }
    else {
        N1 = 0;
    }


    if (N0 == 3 && N1 == 2) {
        document.getElementById('submit').removeAttribute('disabled')
    }
    else {
        if (document.getElementById('submit').hasAttribute('disabled') == true) {

        }
        else {
            document.getElementById('submit').disabled = true
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the `<form>` and `</form>` tags as below:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="h-100 p-5 bg-light border rounded-3">
    <h2>Non-Changable Details</h2>
    <form>  <!-- Remove this tag -->
        ...
    </form> <!-- Remove this tag -->
    </div>
</div>
```

As `@Html.BeginForm()` will generate `<form>` element which the `<form>` element will crash with the `<form>` element mentioned and hence the POST method was not firing.

Meanwhile, will recommend you to read this [article](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/8a67c0/C-Sharp-coding-standards-and-naming-conventions/) for naming convention best practices in C#.

Comment: Thank you very much i was scratching my head for 2 days for these..also thank you for that article, i have also one more problem in this same thing it is showing my modelstate isn't valid how can i fix that?

Comment: `ModelState.IsValid` is false due to there is the properties value was validated and failed. You may check `ModelState.Errors` to see the validation error(s). You may refer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5212248/8017690).