# Model not valid when navigational property is null

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to  ASP mvc and entity framework
I have a model created by entity framework as

```
public partial class Privilege
    {
        public Privilege()
        {
            this.Role_Privilege_Map = new HashSet<Role_Privilege_Map>();
        }

        public int PrivilegeId { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage="*")]
        [Display(Name = "Privilege Name")]
        public string PrivilegeName { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "*")]
        public Nullable<int> ModuleId { get; set; }

        public virtual module module { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Role_Privilege_Map> Role_Privilege_Map { get; set; }
    }
```

As you can see `module` is a navigational property.

I have binded this model to a view as

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => modelItem[i].PrivilegeName)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => modelItem[i].PrivilegeId)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => modelItem[i].PrivilegeName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => modelItem[i].module.ModuleName)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => modelItem[i].ModuleId)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => modelItem[i].module.ModuleName)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => modelItem[i].module)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => modelItem[i].Checked)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => modelItem[i].Checked)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "OpenEditPrivilegeDialog", "RolePrivilegeMapping",
                        new { id = Model[i].PrivilegeId }, 
                        new { @class = "actionHyperLink edit_Privilege_Link" }) |
                    @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "DeletePrivilege","RolePrivilegeMapping",
                        new { id = Model[i].PrivilegeId }, 
                        new { @class = "actionHyperLink Delete_Privilege_Link" })
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
```

I have an Update button for updating this model say Privilege name. Now in my action

```
 public ActionResult UpdateRolePrivilege(IList<One_Track.Models.Privilege> updatedPrivilege)
        {


                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {

                }
                else
                {
                    ViewBag.PrivilegeMessage = "Privileges updation Failed.";
                }
            }

            return PartialView("PrivilegePartial", sample.GetPrivilegeNames());
        }
```

Is returning false. I put a breakpoint and come to know that the navigational property is null that could be a reason for model not been valid. How can I surpass this.  As you can see in code I have added a hidden field for binding navigational property

Why is this happening? Any help will be appreciated

As per the post [ModelState.IsValid == false, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1791570/modelstate-isvalid-false-why/1791664#1791664) provided by wiz kid

I come to know that tan exception is occuring there as

```
The parameter conversion from type 'System.String' to type 'sample.Models.module' failed because no type converter can convert between these types.
   at System.Web.Mvc.ValueProviderResult.ConvertSimpleType(CultureInfo culture, Object value, Type destinationType)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ValueProviderResult.UnwrapPossibleArrayType(CultureInfo culture, Object value, Type destinationType)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ValueProviderResult.ConvertTo(Type type, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.ConvertProviderResult(ModelStateDictionary modelState, String modelStateKey, ValueProviderResult valueProviderResult, Type destinationType)}
```

So I removed the line from view

```
@Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => modelItem[i].module)
```

This solved by problem

Comment: possible duplicate of [ModelState.IsValid == false, why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1791570/modelstate-isvalid-false-why)

Comment: Check this solution for reference http://stackoverflow.com/a/1791664/467853

Comment: @Robert_Junior Is your `navigational Property is null` or it is coming Null ?

Comment: @ Suraj Singh It is coming as null

Comment: @Robert_Junior Just out of curiosity (Since your problem is already solved) Could you please post your Controller code ? Thanks

Comment: @Suraj Singh code added in question

Comment: Because if you inspect your html you will see that you have a hidden input `<input name="[0].module" value="yourAssembly.module" ../>` and a complex object cannot be bound to a string. `@Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => modelItem[i].Checked)` is also nonsense (you already have `@Htlm.CheckBoxFor(modelItem[i].Checked)` so its just ignored)