# MVC MultiSelectList selected items not selected

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

using multiSelectList 
select list displaying, but selected items are not selected.

Debuged code, at the call for ListBox() the multiSelectList member,selectedMembers is populated correctly.Help would be great!

***Update***
Changing name of list box from "members" to anything else makes this work...i.e @Html.ListBox("AnythingExceptmembers", Model.members)

Model

```
    public class GroupProfileViewModel
{
    //primary key
     public int Id { get; set; }

    [StringLength(55, MinimumLength = 3)]
    [Display(Name = "Group Name")]
    public string name { get; set; }

    [StringLength(55, MinimumLength = 3)]
    [Display(Name = "Group Description")]
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public string description { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Date Group Created")]
    public DateTime dateTimeCreated { get; set; }

    public virtual UserAccountModel creator { get; set; }

    public MultiSelectList members { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<GroupModel> groups { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult GetGroupProfile(string groupId)
    {     
            GroupProfileViewModel model;

            ...

            model.members = new  MultiSelectList(db.UserAccounts.ToList(), "Id", "fullName",  groupProfile.members.Select(p => p.Id).ToArray());
            return PartialView("_groupProfilePartial", model);
    }
```

Partial View

```
@model MiTasks.Models.GroupProfileViewModel
<form id="frm_groupProfileForm" method="post" action="/Groups/UpdateGroupProfile">
   ...
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12" style="margin-top:3em;">
         @Html.ListBox("members", Model.members) 
      </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

Partial View Result

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-12" style="margin-top:3em;">
      <select id="members" multiple="multiple" name="members">   
         <option value="1">user1Fname</option>
         <option value="2">user2Fname</option>
      </select> 
   </div>
</div>
```

Debug Picture showing members
[image]

Comment: You need to show your model (unless `members` an array of value types, this wont work)

Comment: Model.members is a MultiSelectList. and I just found the problem (after 2 hours), for what ever reason, you can't name the listbox "members" (same name as the multiselectlist...changing it makes it work, error is reproducible..

Comment: There is an 'edit' link at the bottom of the question :). Also refer this similar [question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30964919/modelstate-isvalid-false/30965017#30965017)

Comment: thanks found it and solved problem, thanks for help tho :)

Comment: I see you found it. You solution may show the correct selection when you render the page, but it will fail as soon as you post (unless you access `AnythingExceptmembers` from the `Request.Form` values). See the link in my previous comment for the correct way to solve this.

Comment: using FormCollection and looping over the members, working, but youre solution is likely the more elegant way :)

Comment: What a dreadful anti-MVC approach. Best of luck.

Comment: yep your right, was not sure how to bind return values of multiSelectList, but using your example and changing "SelectedMusicStyle" to a list<string> works. Thanks :) no more FormCollection