# Bind to complex object using [FromRoute] in ASP.NET Core 3.x gives null

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a simple controller which allows a route path constrained by a regex pattern in a 'complex object'. When I try to read the single property from the object it is always null.

The `ModelState` is showing an errors collection saying:

> The ActorId field is required

So it appears to be a model binding issue and not a validation issue.

I feel like I'm missing a pattern in the `[HttpGet]` block or something.

#### ActorIdParameter.cs

```
public sealed class ActorIdParameter
{
    [Required]
    [RegularExpression(@"^.*nm(\d{5}|\d{7})$")]
    public string ActorId { get; set; }
}
```

#### ActorsController.cs

```
[HttpGet("{actorIdParameter}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetActorByIdAsync([FromRoute]ActorIdParameter actorIdParameter)
{
    _ = actorIdParameter ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(actorIdParameter));
        
    // validation result
    if (!ModelState.IsValid) //<---this is always false
        return ValidationProcessor.GetAndLogInvalidActorIdParameter(method, logger);
}
```

Code is called using this example: http://localhost:4120/api/actors/nm0000206

There are several other posts which deal with the `[FromQuery]` and `[FromBody]` but I can't find anything that deals with the route path. It seems like the `{actorIdParameter}` needs something to say "get the ActorId property within that object" or something.

I feel like I need the complex object for the regex matching. Alternatively I could switch from the `ActorIdParameter` object to a `string` and possibly decorate it inline on the `GetActorByIdAsync` method but I'm curious if anyone has any suggestions?

Comment: How do you call it ? can you paste  that code ?

Comment: Updated original post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update 2023-09-14**:
@JYX reports in comment that the following change is required:
Added `[FromRoute]` to `GetActorByIdAsync`

---

Code below works for me using

```
https://localhost:5001/api/actors/nm0000206
```

and validation fails correctly for this one

```
https://localhost:5001/api/actors/42
```

You don't need any custom handling for this.

```
public class ActorIdParameter
{
    [Required]
    [RegularExpression(@"^.*nm(\d{5}|\d{7})$")]
    [FromRoute]
    public string ActorId { get; set; }
}

[Route("api/actors")]
public class ActorsController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet("{actorId}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetActorByIdAsync([FromRoute] ActorIdParameter model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return new BadRequestResult();
        }

        return new OkResult();
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect. I was trying to line up the parameter name with the 'template' name in the route. I noticed you also can't name the variable after one of the property names of the type.

Comment: This worked for me too, thanks! Just one fix was needed - the `[FromRoute]` attribute is needed on the ActorIdParameter method param. i.e.:

    `public async Task<IActionResult> GetActorByIdAsync([FromRoute] ActorIdParameter model)`

Otherwise, it's expecting the `model` parameter to be provided in the request body.

Comment: Thanks @JYX! Updated the answer with your fix. BR

Answer (score -1):

1. Try to do GET request to those three, change **actors** to your controller route :

- http://url/actors/nm11111
- http://url/actors?actorIdParameter=nm11111
- http://url/actors/?actorIdParameter=nm11111

Is any worked ?

Check you model errors ( to understand why it is false ) :

```
var errors = ModelState
    .Where(x => x.Value.Errors.Count > 0)
    .Select(x => new { x.Key, x.Value.Errors })
    .ToArray();
```

[ModelState.IsValid == false, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1791570/modelstate-isvalid-false-why)

Comment: I have updated my post with the error. I don't think it's failing due to validation.